# How to select all list icons in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After I select the icons I would like to remove the current icon class and add a delete icon

http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/383/

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you show some effort on your part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `removeClass`() and than make use of `addClass()` will do task for this.

here removeClass remove your currrent class and addClass add a class which applyies delete icon.

Answer (score 0):

You could set data-icon=delete

```
<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
```